# why MS Access2013 is giving "you must enter a value in 'Desc' field" when there is a value already?

Tags: ms-access, dao, sharepoint-list

I'm new to MS Access and Sharepoint. I've a requirement to link to a sharepoint list within Access (2013) and Insert new record in this linked table (the table which gets created in the Access when we link the sharepoint list). The linked table has multivalued columns. So I'm using the recordset approach to run the INSERT query. Below is what I'm doing.

```
Option Compare Database
Sub Insert_Query()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs_parent As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rs_child As DAO.Recordset2

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs_parent = dbs.OpenRecordset("TABLENAME")

With rs_parent
.AddNew
![T1] = "test_title"
![W1] = "test_w"
![P1] = "Low"
![A1] = "saleem, Shaik"
![Desc] = "test description"        'LongText type field 'Required Field

Set rs_child = rs_parent![Assigned To].Value
With rs_child
rs_child.AddNew
rs_child!Value = 3160
rs_child.Update
rs_child.Close
End With
rs_parent.Update   'Getting run time error 3314(You must enter a value in  'Desc' Field) on this line

rs_parent.Close

End With

End Sub
```

I've tried changing rs_parent![Desc] to rs_parent.Fields("Desc") and rs_parent.Fiedls(7)---> 7 is the item number in that collection, but all of them are giving the same error.

Any idea what could be the reason for the error and how to fix it please? Feel free to ask me if you need any further information.

Edit: The above error comes only when I execute the procedure when Access is 'online with Sharepoint'. But The same code works just fine if I convert the TABLENAME  into a local table and execute the procedure.